# I keep getting a console warning "Ignoring attempt to ingest data in state ready" from share.uncompressed.js file

Tags: node.js, primus, sharejs

I am using sharejs with primus for real time editing and any time i am about to use or start editing i get the warning "Ignoring attempt to ingest data in state ready" from the share.uncompressed.js script in my browser. Please does anyone know why this warning always appears. Because it seems to slow down the operational transformations that happen behind the scene thereby causing the real time editing to fail at some point. Please does anyone know anything about this.